# Jury rigged ceiling fixture with exposed wiring - what is this?

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

This was found in a 1920s house. There's a ceiling fan/light fixture, insulated(?) cord like you'd find on a floor lamp cord, going down the *outside* of the wall to a switch box, then a 2 prong wall plug. The wiring is probably 1980s or earlier (2 prong power cord with no ground or polarity). The fixture works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Could this have been made any way other than taking a power cord, cutting it in half, and splicing it into a wall switch?
2. Is this as dangerous as it looks?
3. Even with brand new wiring, is there any way to make this as safe as (e.g.) a floor lamp with a wall plug?
4. What is going on inside the box? I've never done electrical work but apparently the top should be hot and the bottom should be neutral, to the fixture. This is the opposite, the bottom goes to the wall plug.
5. If I cut power into the house at the breaker, can I safely cut the wire? The screws on the box are stripped.
6. What would the motivation be? All the other fixtures are hardwired in the wall. Could there be existing in-wall wiring that stopped working, that was sidestepped with this new wiring?

Answer (score -3):

This isn't code so the minutia of arguing isn't useful - is it safe, who knows doesn't matter.   Just swap the switch for a socket and plug it in.

Comment: What would I buy to do that?